# How to choose the bounds of integration for the density function.

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X $and $Y$ are two random variables with joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = c(x+y)$ where $0 < x < y < 1$.

To find $c$, I know that I must integrate the density and equate that to one to find c i.e

$\iint c(x+y)$ = 1 but I am struggling on working out the bounds in which to integrate over. Can anyone clarify a general idea of how I choose the bounds?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection of points $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid 0<x<y<1\}$ is shown in green  in the picture below. Note that for each fixed value of $x$, the values of $y$ ranges from $x$ to $1$. Meanwhile $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. Hence
$$
1=\int_{R} f\, dA=\int_0^1\int_{y=x}^1 c(x+y)\,dy\,dx
$$
which you can compute and find the value of $c$.
[image: Region]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$0 < x < y < 1 \implies 0 < y < 1  \text{ and } 0 < x < y.$$

Comment: I had already tried these bounds before I asked this question but the integration gave me an expression of $y$ meaning that I couldn't solve for C so I gave up, what should I do? I see the other answer but this is just for future reference in preparation for my exam. Thanks for the response, by the way. It's appreciated.